# print specific line in all files in subfolders

Tags: ubuntu, sed

I have a folder with several subfolders, each with several numeric subfolders.

```
├── child1
│   ├── 1
│   ├── 2
│   └── 3
├── child2
│   ├── 1
│   ├── 2
│   └── 3
└── child3
    ├── 1
    ├── 2
    └── 3
```

Each numeric folder has a file named `pos`

I want to  print line 100 of each `pos` file in each folder numbered `3`

I can list the folders with:

```
find . -type d -name "3" -exec find {} -type f -name "pos" \;
```

How can I print line 100 of each file?
The output should something like:

```
./child1/3/pos: content of line 100
./child2/3/pos: content of line 100
./child3/3/pos: content of line 100
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Append this to your "find":
... `| while read f ; do echo "$f: $(tail -n +100 ""$f"" | head -n 1 )" ; done`

*TESTED*

This is general Bash code; learn more about it in the "Bash guides" at [www.tldp.org](http://www.tldp.org) - just browsing will tell you a lot - these are old, but still contains very much valid info.

Comment: This one is not working for me. I keep on getting:
`tail: cannot open '"./child1/3/pos"' for reading: No such file or directory` `tail: cannot open 'with' for reading: No such file or directory`

Comment: Edited, check if it works better.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed` it is easy to print line 100 for all files, but I didn't find a pure `sed` solution to prefix the line with the file name.

```
sed -ns 100p */3/pos
```

To print the file name you could use a shell loop. This will create a separate `sed` process for every file.

```
for i in */3/pos
do
    sed -n "100{s|^|$i: |;p}" "$i"
done
```

or

```
for i in */3/pos
do
    echo "$i: $(sed -n 100p "$i")"
done
```

Alternatively you can use `awk`.

```
awk 'FNR==100 { print FILENAME ": " $0 }' */3/pos
```

Comment: The `awk` works for me!, can It sort the ouput?

Comment: @R.Smith In which way do you want to sort the output? You can always pipe the command output to `sort` (with appropriate arguments if necessary).